# M2 - How to get attribute on Product Page showing above title

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3.4, position, pdp

I am using custom theme inherit from blank theme, i want to display my attribute on product page above title, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

in catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="content" before="-"/>
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.before.title" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/before_title.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

and then create your Phtml : Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/before_title.html

```
<?php

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */

$_product = $block->getProduct();
$custom = $_product->getData('custom_attribute');

?>

<?= $custom ?>
```